# Issues with Spring batch Metadata tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have been trying to create a Spring batch program which has to read certain data from Database and write it into another table. I don't want the Spring Batch metadata tables to be created in my Database. When I tried that, I was not able to do the transactions.

I avoided the meta data tables by extending `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and overriding like this,

```
@Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }
```

By doing this I was getting `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` exception.

Is there a way by which I can avoid the metadata tables and still use the transactions?

Comment: Are you talking about ResourcelessTransactionManager and MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean?

Comment: Yes. I understand by using `ResourcelessTransactionManager` and `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` I can avoid those table creations. But I am not able to persist any data into Database, which I have to do as part of my batch Job.

Comment: So us your code & configuration

Answer (score 1):

1. If your are using spring boot you may add the below line to application.properties or environment specific property file to ensure the spring batch metadata tables are not getting created:

`spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false`

2. Also since you do not need the meta tables so do not extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class.
3. I would only extend this class if I want to set up a persistent `JobRepository` i.e. create the spring batch meta tables, for which we need a lot of other configurations that are provided by default by `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class.